# How do I serialize this into JSON?

Tags: javascript, python, json, datetime, serialization

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ccb42cb8aad692e01000004"),
    "loc" : {
        "lat" : 37.799506,
        "long" : -122.459445
    },
    "test_set" : 1,
    "title" : "Melissa Mills Housewife 01 SIGNED",
    "num_comments" : 58,
    "down_votes" : 66,
    "up_votes" : 79,
    "image_url" : "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1374/5126544615_79170591e5_m.jpg",
    "image_url_thumb" : "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1374/5126544615_79170591e5_t.jpg",
    "date" : "Fri Oct 29 2010 21:55:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
    "flickr_id" : "5126544615"
}
```

One of the elements in thelist is above.

```
thejson = simplejson.dumps({"results":thelist})
```

However, I can't serialize this because of the `date` field.  It can't serialize datetime.

Comment: why not convert the date field into a unix timestamp?

Comment: In the above code, the date is a string. Can't you just serialize a string?

Comment: According to above, the `date` field contains a `String`, not a `datetime`. It's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish here though. Either way, you should be able to convert a `datetime` to a `String` and serialize the dictionary.

Comment: Please include the actual error message.  And the actual version of Python you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt that the problem has to do anything with datetime: in your dictionary, there is no datetime object at all, but the "date" key has a regular string value.

More likely, the problem is that it can't serialize the ObjectId class. To overcome this limitation, create a new class inheriting from `JSONEncoder`, and overriding the [`default`](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.1.2/docs/index.html#simplejson.JSONEncoder.default) method.

Comment: This is what it says: Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 29, 23, 48, 22, 108000) is not JSON serializable

Comment: That most likely means that the value you are trying to marshal is not the one you posted in your original message.

Answer (score 1):

Unless i'm missing something - its the `ObjectId` that is causing the error (works for me here without it). You might want to consider munging or removing that field if not needed. 
The date parses fine.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I have removed ObjectId as I do not have the class with me.

```
result = {
    "loc" : {
        "lat" : 37.799506,
        "long" : -122.459445
    },
    "test_set" : 1,
    "title" : "Melissa Mills Housewife 01 SIGNED",
    "num_comments" : 58,
    "down_votes" : 66,
    "up_votes" : 79,
    "image_url" : "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1374/5126544615_79170591e5_m.jpg",
    "image_url_thumb" : "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1374/5126544615_79170591e5_t.jpg",
    "date" : "Fri Oct 29 2010 21:55:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
    "flickr_id" : "5126544615"
}

import simplejson

thejson = simplejson.dumps(result)

print thejson
```

Output:

```
{"down_votes": 66, "loc": {"lat": 37.799506000000001, "long": -122.459445}, "image_url": "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1374/5126544615_79170591e5_m.jpg", "test_set": 1, "title": "Melissa Mills Housewife 01 SIGNED", "up_votes": 79, "num_comments": 58, "image_url_thumb": "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1374/5126544615_79170591e5_t.jpg", "date": "Fri Oct 29 2010 21:55:23 GMT+0000 (UTC)", "flickr_id": "5126544615"}
```

And if you are getting the following error, then you need to have class ObjectId :

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ccb42cb8aad692e01000004"),
NameError: name 'ObjectId' is not defined
```